# Log4j jar removed when building WAR in Grails

Tags: grails, tomcat7, grails-plugin

Here's my log4j snippet from Config.groovy

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{2} - %m\n')
        rollingFile name:'file', file:'/home/user/logs/app.log', maxFileSize:'5MB', maxBackupIndex:2
    }

    root {
        info "stdout"
    }

    info file: "grails.app"
}
```

And here's my BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" 
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    inherits("global") {
        excludes 'serializer'
    }

    log "warn" 
    checksums true 

    repositories {
        inherits true 

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'
        compile "commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1"
        compile "it.svario.xpathapi:xpathapi-jaxp:0.3"

        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3'
        build 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
        build 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3'
        runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.1'
        runtime 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
   }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
        compile ":rest:0.8"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        compile ':cache:1.0.0'
        compile ":spring-events:1.2"
    }
}

grails.plugin.location.'module' = "../module"
```

The grails version used is 2.2.4. When `grails run-app`, it works fine. When the war is built, the WAR doesn't contain the log4j library in it.

If we manually add the library, the exception is suppressed. However, the log isnt written to app.log.

Can someone provide a solution to this ?

**Update :** There is Quartz 1.0-RC9 plugin used within this application. Is there a chance this is conflicting with log4j ?

Comment: Run `grails dependency-report` to see whether quartz has the problem. I feel you are correct in spotting that out.

Comment: @dmahapatro: Thanks. Tried out above command. No errors reported in dependency-report. Can see log4j library in classpath in IDE. Only when building into WAR (from IDE or command prompt) it is missing in WAR.